# Which algorithm does Ruby's sort method use?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

When I sort an Array using the native `sort` method, which algorithm does Ruby use?

Is it data-dependant, i.e., if the data is small it uses X algorithm else it uses Y algorithm?

Is it a stable sort? What is the average time complexity?

Comment: The stability of Ruby's sort is addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442298/is-sort-in-ruby-stable).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Look here: http://www.igvita.com/2009/03/26/ruby-algorithms-sorting-trie-heaps/

It does natively use quicksort however, which is n log n complexity on average.

Comment: This also means it is most likely not a stable sort.  See the explanations of this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_sort

Comment: True, especially if the array is almost sorted, then quick sort's complexity becomes n^2. Still, it is extremely fast in most cases.

Comment: If the array is almost sorted, only a stupid quicksort goes to n^2. Median of three pivot selection is in all implementattions I've used

Comment: @Stephan Eggermont: As far as I know, also median of three pivot is n^2 in the worse case.

Comment: Not for an almost sorted array, which is near worst case for a stupid pivot selection (first element)

Comment: I'm wondering if the word "stupid" is actually a technical word for describing these algorithms

Comment: @CarlosMartinez The technical term for "stupid" is "naive".