# Sorting query results using a model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following mapping (`@location_matches` represents a standard SQL query`:

```
 @matches = @location_matches.map { |listing|

    }.compact
```

When I go to my view, I can access @matches.username, etc, etc, etc.

However when I add this model method, I lose all access to any of the info!

```
 @matches = @location_matches.map { |listing|
           listing.compute_score(current_user)

    }.compact
```

any ideas why? is there a better way to do this? thank ya

Comment: `map` returns an array of the results of the block applied, so all you're getting is an array of computed scores. What were you after originally?

Comment: I stink at this! I'm trying to compute a score based on what is returned from the query and then I want to sort the results by that computed score. I'm trying everything every which way (and wrong way). Any ideas? Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's sorting by computed score:

```
@matches = @location_matches.sort_by{|location| location.compute_score(current_user)}
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001481

Put `.reverse` at the end if you want it reverse-sorted.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! What do l1 and l2 represent? I'm sure this works, just wondering if you could help me understand. Thanks again!

Comment: Haha you're more confident than me, please try it first. `sort` does a comparison sort, so `l1` and `l2` represents each pair of values being compared... in this case, each of your matched objects.

Comment: haha thanks - i'll give it a shot, when you mean pair of values being compared what are you referring to? do you mean it's like a step by step comparison? like it will compare the first to next and so on?

Comment: Here's a question that goes into Ruby's sort algorithms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855773/which-algorithm-does-rubys-sort-method-use

Comment: Thanks -- do you know how I could reverse the sort?

Comment: To reverse: flip the left and right sides of the `<=>`... (put l2 on the left and l1 on the right).

Comment: I think [`sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001481) would be a better call than `sort` for anything expensive (like `compute_score` probably is).