# Ruby combined comparison operator sorting

Tags: ruby, sorting, operator-keyword

The following code sorts the array in ascending order.

```
my_array = [2, 3, 1, 5, 4]
my_array.sort! { |n1, n2| n1 <=> n2 }
```

I read that the `<=>` operator returns `-1` if the first object is less than the second object and `0` if first object is equal to second object and `1` if first object is greater than second object.

How could this information lead to sorting the list? I want to know how the given code works.

If we swap the items around the `<=>` operator the array gets sorted in descending order. But how?

Comment: You can refer to documentation and source:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-sort!

Comment: That didn't helped me.

Comment: So you should explain what you don't understand better.

Comment: I don't understand the mechanism that the sort function uses, using the values returned by comparison operator to sort the function in ascending order.

Comment: @user3544994, if you know something about algebra, you may know about inversions. the inversion is a core meaning of sorting.

Comment: Maybe this video can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywWBy6J5gz8 (quick-sort is actually the sorting algorithm implemented by Ruby `Array#sort`)

Comment: Why do we use "<=>"? Why can't a simple "<" work here?

Comment: @gaussblurinc Hahaha!

Comment: @user3544994, just think about how you manipulate with two different elements in array. yes, you can use here '<' and '==' instead of spaceship operator. first, you answer: "is these two elements equal?", next you answer: "they are not equal. ok. does first element smaller than second?". spaceship operator collapse these two questions in one

Answer (score 1):

There are many [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) out there (ruby uses [quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855773/which-algorithm-does-rubys-sort-method-use)), but all of them have one acceptance test: for every element `a[n]` in array `a` `a[n] <= a[n+1]`.

What the block in the `sort!` method should return is what does `<=` mean. If that's known - sorting can happen - that is all that is needed to be known to the algorithm, since it can compare any two elements in the array and know whether they should be swapped or not.

When you swap `n1` with `n2`, you simply say that for this call you want `<=` to actually mean `>=`, which reverses the eventual order of the array...

---

Ruby needs the elaborate `<=>` since operators like `<` return one of two possible results - `true` and `false`.

If we used `<`, for example, for `[5, 5]` the algorithm may ask `a[0] < a[1]` which will return `false`, so the algorithm will swap them, but then again `a[0] < a[1]` will return `false`, and the algorithm might fail.

In the best case scenario - there will be an excess of operations and the performance will suffer, in the worst case - the algorithm may never finish...

Comment: Hi, I understand that if sort function knows the result of "<=>" it can sort the array but my question is how does it does that so I can understand why swapping the objects result in sorting of array in descending order.

Comment: You want to know how the sorting algorithm works? As I say in my answer - ruby uses quicksort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). There are simpler algorithms like insertion sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), or selection sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)...

Comment: I am not asking how the sorting algorithm works. I am asking why do we need a fancy looking "<=>" which returns weird 1, 0 and -1. Couldn't Ruby makers have simplified things by using "<" operator instead of complex looking "<=>" operator?

Comment: @user3544994 tried to give specific explanation for the `<=>` operator. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is done according to the value of the block evaluated with each pair of elements of the array. If you have a `<=>` statement inside the block, the value will be either `-1`, `0`, or `1` as you know. There is a natural sorting order defined on some class. In case of numerals, they follow the inequality order in the conventional mathematical sense, that is `-1` comes before `0`, which is before `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at all the different [Sorting Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and you will begin to understand how the comparison of two elements can be used to implement a sorting algorithm for a list of elements.

These [visualisations](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) might help to better comprehend the differences between the algorithms.