# How does `sort` work when `<=>` is not an order relation?

Tags: ruby, sorting

Suppose I define the `<=>` relation among elements so that it is not an order relation (i.e., it does not satisfy some of reflexivity, antisymmetry, transitivity).

```
class Scissors
  def <=> other
    case other
    when Scissors then 0
    when Paper then 1
    when Rock then -1
    end
  end
end

class Paper
  def <=> other
    case other
    when Scissors then -1
    when Paper then 0
    when Rock then 1
    end
  end
end

class Rock
  def <=> other
    case other
    when Scissors then 1
    when Paper then -1
    when Rock then 0
    end
  end
end
```

When I call `sort` (non-Schwartzian comparison) among such elements, I get a certain result:

```
scissors = Scissors.new
paper = Paper.new
rock = Rock.new

[rock, paper, scissors].sort
# =>
# [
#   #<Rock:0x007f7a64ffaa10>,
#   #<Paper:0x007f7a64ffaa38>,
#   #<Scissors:0x007f7a64ffaa60>
# ]

[scissors, paper, rock].sort
# =>
# [
    #<Scissors:0x007f7a64ffaa60>,
    #<Rock:0x007f7a64ffaa10>,
    #<Paper:0x007f7a64ffaa38>
# ]
```

What logic does `sort` follow in such case?

Comment: Seems like this would be very implementation-specific. Can we assume you're referring specifically to MRI?

Comment: the sort predicate requires strict ordering which is not the case if comparing scissors-paper-rock. For a big group, a partition sort will pick one element then put everything less than it on one side, everything greater the other, so you'll end up with all your papers, then all your scissors, then all your rocks if the pivot picked is a scissors object. If a different one that will end up in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the order Ruby compares elements in an array, use the next trick:

```
[rock, paper, scissors].sort {|x,y| p [x,y]; x<=>y}
[#<Paper:0x000000080407d8>, #<Scissors:0x00000007e91c70>]
[#<Rock:0x000000080fce88>, #<Paper:0x000000080407d8>]
#=> [#<Rock:0x000000080fce88>, #<Paper:0x000000080407d8>, #<Scissors:0x00000007e91c70>]

[scissors, paper, rock].sort {|x,y| p [x,y]; x<=>y}
[#<Paper:0x000000080407d8>, #<Rock:0x000000080fce88>]
[#<Scissors:0x00000007e91c70>, #<Rock:0x000000080fce88>]
#=> [#<Scissors:0x00000007e91c70>, #<Rock:0x000000080fce88>, #<Paper:0x000000080407d8>]
```

As you see, Ruby starts comparing from the end to the beginning of the Array.
On each iteration Ruby compares the objects and if the second object is less than the first they will be swapped.

Comment: It is a bit unclear. In the first case, the second comparison is rock to paper, which are adjacent in the original array. In the second case, the second comparison is scissors to rock, which are at the both ends of the original array.

Comment: `[scissors, paper, rock]` after the first iteration transform into `[scissors, rock, paper]`, because `paper` more than `rock`, and Ruby swap it. Ruby modify array inplace for memory economy, i think

Comment: That does not explain why `[3, 2, 1]` can be sorted to `[1, 2, 3]`. According to your explanation, first `2` and `1` are compared, giving `[3, 1, 2]`. Then, `3` and `1` should be compared, giving `[1, 3, 2`].

Comment: So, are you saying that it is following bubble sort?

Comment: IMHO it makes sense that Ruby uses bubble sort for such a small array. Since bubble sort is more efficient than quick sort or merge sort for small `N`. I wouldn't be surprised if Ruby would check the size of the input first and then uses different algorithms depending on the number of elements in the array.

Comment: The [`sort!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-sort-21) documentation looks like Ruby's using quick sort. Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/855773/128421